# "Invalid description in FETCH_HEAD" pull / sync in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, libgit2

In Visual Studio 2013 when pulling my repository from GitHub:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2.
>   Category = 20 (Error). Invalid description in FETCH_HEAD line 2

From the command line, `git pull` and `git push` say everything is up to date, as normal.

Here is the libgit2 source code that generates this error message:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ALEXBIO/Git-Raw-0.27/xs/libgit2/src/fetchhead.c

Comment: Maybe libgit2 has bugs

Comment: Can you please provide the content of the `.git\FETCH_HEAD` file that triggers this parsing issue?

Comment: problematic .git\FETCH_HEAD file:   http://pastebin.com/TUqSfpQs

Comment: The problem is presumably `Tansen's-Input-Refactor` which includes the quote both as delimiter and as part of the branch name.

Comment: @linquize It doesn't really matter whether this bug is in libgit2, LibGit2Sharp or Visual Studio itself, except as an academic exercise.  Fundamentally, this is a Visual Studio bug since it impacts this scenario in Visual Studio.  I regret it and we will include Carlos' helpful fix as quickly as we can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the libgit2 library, which overlooked the fact that a single quote character might appear as part of a valid reference name.

There's [a fix for libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2295) in the works, but short-term you might want to stay away from branches or tags with quote chars in them as a work-around.

Make sure to raise this via the official Visual Studio support channels so they can track this in their system as a bug.

Comment: This is now a bug logged for VS 2013.

Comment: and it's still not fixed as of Jan 2017 in VS2013 Update 5

Comment: @JerryGoyal then you should tell Microsoft, there's nothing anybody reading this can do about it